# Remove rows in csv if the first column is text or blank, and only keep the row if the first column is number

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file which has alternate sets of text and numbers. I want to delete the text and only keep the numbers in the file. If the first column of any row has text or is blank, I would want to remove the row. How can I achieve this in Python?

I tried different lines of code (below) but none seems to be working. Can anyone please help? Thanks

```
#dataset.drop(dataset[str.isdigit(dataset[:, 0])].index, inplace=True)
#dataset = dataset[~dataset['No'].str]
#dataset[dataset[:, 0].apply(lambda x: str(x).isdigit())]
#dataset[dataset["No"].str.contains("A")==False]
#dataset = dataset.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True).dropna()
#dataset.columns = ['Rec', 'Depth', 'Time', 'Cone', 'Friction', 'Pore2', '']
#dataset = dataset.dropna(subset=['Rec'])
#dataset = dataset[dataset.Rec != '']  
#indexNames = set(('Program', 'CSV', 'Project number', 'ASCII file created at', 'time', 'Output based 
upon command file', 'Date of testing', 'Location', 'Test name', 'Serial', 'Table', 'Column', 'Rec', 
'Depth', 'Time', 'Cone', 'Friction', 'Pore2'))
#dataset = dataset.loc[~dataset.Rec.str.contains("Program", "CSV")
#dataset.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors = 'coerce')).dropna()
#dataset.drop(dataset[str.isdigit(dataset[:,0])].index, inplace=True)
#dataset = dataset.filter(regex='a-zA-Z')
```

[image: Image of csv file]

Comment: Have you tried `skiprows=` parameter in `.read_csv()`? Something like `df=pd.read_csv("file.csv", skiprows=14)`

Comment: the set of text and number keeps on repeating (alternate rows of text and rows of numbers). With skiprow, I can remove the first n rows, but not the ones that occur in between the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this CSV file:

```
some text
more text

1,a,b,c,d
2,b,b,c,d
3,c,b,c,d

some text
more text

4,d,b,c,d
5,e,b,c,d
6,f,b,c,d
```

Then you can do (`re.match` will match lines which start with number):

```
import re
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO


r_line = re.compile(r"\d")
lines = [line for line in open("your file.txt", "r") if r_line.match(line)]

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("\n".join(lines)), names=["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"])
print(df)
```

To create this dataframe:

```
  c1 c2 c3 c4
1  a  b  c  d
2  b  b  c  d
3  c  b  c  d
4  d  b  c  d
5  e  b  c  d
6  f  b  c  d
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the response. Does the script you provided work for the following table? I applied your code, but could not make it work.

Table description   
Column ID Parameter 
Data table:      
Rec Depth Time
1 0.75 150.5    
2 0.77 151.47    
3 0.79 152.44    
4 0.81 153.41    
5 0.83 154.38
      
Table description   
Column ID Parameter name   
Rec Record ID Record ID [-]    
Depth Depth Depth [m]   
Data table:      
Rec Depth Time
1 8.5 330.5    
2 8.52 331.57    
3 8.54 332.63    
      
Table description: